# Oracle query not returning null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I was expecting the following query to return null rows where there wasn't a matching row in the WEBSITE_URL table when using the left join.
So what i want to see is all url types from the URLTYPE table and any matching records in the WEBSITE_URL table.

```
SELECT
    WU.NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK,
    WU.TC_URL,
    UT.TC_URLTYPE_NAME
  FROM
    WEBSITE_URL WU,
    URLTYPE UT
  WHERE
    WU.NC_URL_TYPE_ID_FK(+) = UT.NC_URLTYPE_ID
  AND
    NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK = '1622'
```

This is the output:

```
1622    http://www.test.com                 PRODUCTION (PUBLIC)

1622    http://preprod.test.com             PREPRODUCTION

1622    http://review.test.com              REVIEW
```

Comment: select * from WEBSITE_URL where NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK = '1622' and NC_URL_TYPE_ID_FK not in (select NC_URLTYPE_ID from URLTYPE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    WU.NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK,
    WU.TC_URL,
    UT.TC_URLTYPE_NAME
  FROM
    URLTYPE UT
  LEFT JOIN 
    WEBSITE_URL WU ON WU.NC_URL_TYPE_ID_FK = UT.NC_URLTYPE_ID
               AND WU.NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK = '1622'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard join type (outer or left in this case) rather than just in the old sql syntax

```
SELECT WU.NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK, WU.TC_URL, UT.TC_URLTYPE_NAME
FROM URLTYPE UT
FULL OUTER JOIN WEBSITE_URL WU ON UT.NC_URLTYPE_ID = WU.NC_URL_TYPE_ID_FK(+)
WHERE NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK = '1622'
```

Comment: Please add some context instead of just spitting up some code.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  Few people really understand the old Oracle syntax anymore.

Second, use table aliases on all the columns.

If `NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK` comes from `WEBSITE_URL`, then the condition needs to be moved to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT WU.NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK, WU.TC_URL, UT.TC_URLTYPE_NAME
FROM URLTYPE LEFT JOIN
     WEBSITE_URL WU
     ON WU.NC_URL_TYPE_ID_FK = UT.NC_URLTYPE_ID AND
        NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK = '1622';
```

Also, if `NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK` is a number, don't put the constant value in single quotes.  It is misleading both to people and to the optimizer to mix data types.

Comment: This is close to the output that I am after, the only thing that its not doing is outputting the NC_WEBSITE_ID_FK in the null rows, which i'm not sure is possible.

Comment: @JeepersCreepers . . . If there is no match, how would it have a value for that column?